# Problem in linked list while using struct variable

Tags: c, linked-list

Code for linked list using memory allocation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *point;

};
int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    head=(struct node* )  malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    void create(struct node* start);
    void print(struct node* start);


    create(head);
    print(head);

    return 0;
}
void create(struct node* start)
{
    int test,a=1;
    struct node* cur;
    cur=start;

    while(scanf("%d",&test)!=EOF)
    {       if(a!=1)
            {
                cur=cur->point;
            }
            cur->point=(struct node* )  malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
            cur->val=test;

            a++;
            printf("---------------");
            printf("%d\n",cur);
            printf("%d\n",cur->val);
            printf("%d\n",cur->point);
            printf("%d\n",a);
            printf("---------------");
    }
    cur->point=NULL;
    return;
}
void print(struct node* start)
{
        struct node* cur;
        cur=start;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ",cur->val);
            cur=cur->point;
        }

        return;
}
```

Code for linked list using struct variable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *point;

};
int main()
{
    struct node *head,link;
    head=&link;
    void create(struct node* start);
    void print(struct node* start);


    create(head);
    print(head);

    return 0;
}
void create(struct node* start)
{
    int test,a=1;
    struct node* cur;
    cur=start;

    while(scanf("%d",&test)!=EOF)
    {   if(a!=1)
        {
            cur=cur->point;

        }
        struct node link;
        cur->point=&link;
        cur->val=test;

        a++;

        printf("---------------");
        printf("%d\n",cur);
        printf("%d\n",cur->val);
        printf("%d\n",cur->point);
        printf("%d\n",&link);
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("---------------");
    }
    cur->point=NULL;
    return;
}
void print(struct node* start)
{
     struct node* cur;
     cur=start;
     while(cur!=NULL)
     {
        printf("%d ",cur->val);
        cur=cur->point;
     }

     return;
}
```

When I use 2nd code it doesn't work correctly. It prints just two values.

In while loop of create() I use struct node type variable declaration.

That's why it should it would declare a new struct node type link variable and a new memory (struct node link) address should be seen in every execution.

So what's the problem?

I am a newbie learning data structure using C. Please explain in simple language.

Comment: `cut->point = &link;` You are trying to store the address of a local variable. Use `malloc` instead.

Comment: Neither example should compile. Function prototypes should come before `main`, not nested within.

Comment: Though link variable (in while statement) is a local variable but i am pointing it.So it's should be seen.Otherwise it point  no local variable.But it point only one variable.And that's one cann't point  2nd link variable (which is declared in 2nd executuion of while loop.).If you compile code you would understand well.  @Johnny

Comment: Johnny Mopp is correct.  Your pointer is pointing to garbage on the second loop because the local variable that it was pointing to is gone.